# Low count of data frames in wifi monitor mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-monitoring, frame

I am using *scapy* to gather stats about wifi traffic for a given *MAC*. I log the date, type, subtype, and rssi of packets I capture in monitor mode with scapy.

And I see a **very low count of data frames** (type 2, subtype 0). Why ?

For example, I initiated the download of a **8MB** file and the count increased by one or two.

As data frames are approx. **2k** in size, I would except a fair amount of data frames being seen for such a download.

The wifi connexion is on a 802.11n with WPA2 on channel 1 captured with a TP-Link *TL-WN722N* on a **rpi3** running archlinux-arm.

**Edit**:
I tried by setting the channel bandwidth to HT40+  (with `iw dev wlan1mon set channel 1 HT40+)` but I did not see more *Data frames* either.

Does it have to do with the number of antennas ? the TL-WN722N has only one antenna while the AP has 2, and I guess the latpop too.

But why would I see the other frames, then ?

**Edit2**:
So using `tshark -i wlan1mon -Y 'wlan.fc.type_subtype == 0x20' -n -t a -T tabs`, I discovered that I am seeing only packet to **broadcast** or **multicast** mac like `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`, `33:33:00:00:00:01`, `01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa`

Even if I set the interface in promiscious mode, it is still the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 802.11n and 802.11ac require QOS (WMM, 802.11e), so all data is sent as Data/QOS-Data (type 2 subtype 8) frames nowadays.

Data/Data (type 2 subtype 0) is a vanishing relic of the bygone a/b/g era.